# classifier4J with compound words

Tags: java, bayesian

I'm using the *BayesianClassifier* class to classify spam. The problem is that compound words aren't being recognized.

For instance if I add *led zeppelin* as a match, a sentence containing it won't be recognized as a match even though it should.

For adding a match I'm using *addMatch()* of *SimpleWordsDataSource*

And for asking for a match I'm using *isMatch()* of *BayesianClassifier*

Any ideas on how to fix this?

---

Ok, thanks for the insight. I'm attaching more source code.

```
SimpleWordsDataSource wds = new SimpleWordsDataSource();
BayesianClassifier classifier = new BayesianClassifier(wds);

wds.addMatch("queen");
wds.addMatch("led zeppelin");
wds.addMatch("the beatles");

classifier.isMatch("i listen to queen");// it is recognized as a match
classifier.isMatch("i listen to led zeppelin");// it is NOT recognized as a match
classifier.isMatch("i listen to the beatles");// it is NOT recognized as a match
```

---

Now I'm using the teachMatch method of BayesianClassifier and I've got different results.
A sentence containing *led zeppelin* it is classified as a match, which is ok. But a sentence including *led* it is also classified as a match, which is wrong.

Here's the relevant code:

```
BayesianClassifier classifier = new BayesianClassifier();
classifier.teachMatch("led zeppelin");
classifier.isMatch("I listen to led zeppelin");//true
classifier.isMatch("I listen to led");//true
```

Comment: Not without code.  The information your provided is worthless.

Answer (score 4):

(I wrote classifier4j)

You need to train it with more data.

Bayesian classifiers work by creating statistical models of what is considered a match and what isn't.

If you give it enough data, it will learn that "led and zeppelin" is a match, but "led" by itself isn't